# React + redux. When dispatch event in reducer. both reducers get the same data

Tags: reactjs, redux

I recently started using redux for a new personal project. It worked pretty well until I started using "combineReducers". Whenever I click "Fetch todos" both my user as well as my todo reducer get updated and even though they have different data field names both get the same data. Now I probably did some wrong encapsulation here. But no matter how often I went over the docs, I just cannot see what I am doing wrong.

My store initialization script:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import toDoReducer from './todos/reducer';
import userReducer from './users/reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    todosSlice: toDoReducer,
    usersSlice: userReducer
});

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export default store;
```

gets injected into index:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './containers/app/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import configureStore  from './store/configureStore';

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={ configureStore }><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

My app hold the logic for the todo container

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as todoActions from '../../store/todos/actions';
import UserContainer from '../usersContainer/UserContainer';

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    let loading = '';
    let error = '';
    let todos = [];

    // check whether the component is fetching data
    this.props.loading === true ? loading = <p>Loading...</p> : loading = '';

    // check if there was an error
    this.props.error  && this.props.loading === false ? error = <p>There was an error</p> : error = '';

    // map the todos in the desired html markup.
    todos = this.props.todos.map( todo => {
      return <div key={todo.id}>  name: {todo.title} </div>
    });

    return (
      <div className="App">

        {/* <UserContainer /> */}

        {loading}
        {error}

        <p onClick={() => this.props.onFetchTodos()}>Fetch Todos</p>

        {todos}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    error: state.todosSlice.error,
    loading: state.todosSlice.loading,
    todos: state.todosSlice.todos
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onFetchTodos: () => dispatch(todoActions.fetchTodos())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Which has the following actions:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const FETCH_TODOS = 'FETCH_TODOS';
export const GET_TODOS_STARTED = 'GET_TODOS_STARTED';
export const FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE';

export const fetchRequest = () => {
    return dispatch => {

        dispatch(getTodoStarted());

        axios.get('https://one365-api-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/teams/')
            .then(result => {
                dispatch(fetchTodosSucces(result));
            }).catch(error => {
                dispatch(fetchTodoFailure(error));
            });
    }

}

const getTodoStarted = () => ({
    type: GET_TODOS_STARTED
});

const fetchTodosSucces = todos => ({
    type: FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS,
    payload: {
      ...todos
    }
});

const fetchTodoFailure = error => ({
    type: FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE,
    payload: {
      error
    }
});

export const fetchTodos = () => {
    return (dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchRequest());
    });
}
```

And it's reducer

```
import * as actions from './actions';

const initialState = {
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    todos: []
}

const todosReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch(action.type) {

        case actions.GET_TODOS_STARTED: {
            console.log('fetch todo state', state)

            return {
                ...state,
                loading: state.loading = true
            };
        }

        case actions.FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS: {
            const todos = action.payload.data;
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                todos: state.todos = todos
            };
        }

        case actions.FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE: {
            const error = action.payload.error;

            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: state.error = error
            };
        }

        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}

export default todosReducer;
```

The Users Component

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';

    import * as userActions from '../../store/users/actions';

    class UserContainer extends React.Component {

        render () {
            let loading = '';
            let error = '';
            let users = [];

            // check whether the component is fetching data
            this.props.usersLoading === true ? loading = <p>Loading...</p> : loading = '';

            // check if there was an error
            this.props.usersError  && this.props.loading === false ? error = <p>There was an error</p> : error = '';

            // map the users in the desired html markup.
            users = this.props.users.map( user => {
              return <div key={user.id}>  name: {user.title} </div>
            });

            return (
              <div className="Users">

                {loading}
                {error}

                <p onClick={() => this.props.onFetchUsers()}>Fetch Users</p>

                {users}
              </div>
            );
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            usersError: state.usersSlice.error,
            usersLoading: state.usersSlice.loading,
            users: state.usersSlice.users
        }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps= (dispatch) => {
        return {
            onFetchUsers: () => dispatch(userActions.fetchUsers())
        }    
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserContainer);

the user actions:
import axios from 'axios';
export const FETCH_USERS = 'FETCH_TODOS';
export const FETCH_USERS_STARTED = 'GET_TODOS_STARTED';
export const FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_USERS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE';


export const fetchRequest = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchUsersStarted());

        axios.get('https://one365-api-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/me')
            .then(result => {
                dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(result));
            }).catch(error => {
                dispatch(fetchUsersFailure(error));
            });
    }
}


export const fetchUsersSuccess = (users) => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS,
        payload: {
            ...users
        }
    }
}

export const fetchUsersStarted = () => ({
    type: FETCH_USERS_STARTED
});

export const fetchUsersFailure = (error) => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_USERS_FAILURE,
        payload: {
            error
        }
    }
}



export const fetchUsers = () => {
    return dispatch =>  {
        dispatch(fetchRequest()) 
    }
};
```

And it's reducer:

```
import * as actions from './actions';

const initialState = {
    error: '',
    loading: false,
    users: []
}

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch(action.type) {

        case actions.FETCH_USERS_STARTED:  {
            console.log('fetch users state', state)
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: state.loading = true
            }
        } 

        case actions.FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS: {
            const users = action.payload.data;
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                users: state.users = users
            }
        }

        case actions.FETCH_USERS_FAILURE: {
            const error = state.payload.error;
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: state.error = error    
            }
        }

        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }

}


export default userReducer;
```

Now when I run my DEV server I only see the fetch todo button. I commented out the users on click handler to see if it was an event bubble going up. Bu t this wasn't the case.

Once the app load redux dev tools shows the state as follows:
[image]

but once i click the fetch todo's handler. Both todos and users get filled.
[image]

I appreciate anyone who read though so much (boilerplate) code. I probably made  a problem encapsulating my state. but again after reading many tutorials I still cannot find my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a copy/paste issue. You changed the names of the constants for your "USERS" actions, but left the values the same as the "TODOS" actions.

```
export const FETCH_USERS = 'FETCH_TODOS';
export const FETCH_USERS_STARTED = 'GET_TODOS_STARTED';
export const FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_USERS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE';
```

I assume you meant to have:

```
export const FETCH_USERS = 'FETCH_USERS';
export const FETCH_USERS_STARTED = 'FETCH_USERS_STARTED';
export const FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_USERS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_USERS_FAILURE';
```

Comment: My god, I feel ashamed of myself... Thanks for pointing it out, and will upvote when it is allowed.